# Writing an 2D array to a range of cells

Tags: vba

I've got an array of a range of cells and I need to write it back to a specific range of cells. My first 2 columns are working as desired when writing back to the new range of cells but the next 2 columns are mirroring column 2 for columns 3 and 4.

Array Range:

```
1,2,3,4

2,2,3,5

3,4,5,6
```

will write as:

```
1,2,2,2

2,2,2,2

3,4,4,4
```

What I want is:

```
1,2,3,4

2,2,3,5

3,4,5,6
```

```
Dim myRange As Range
Dim scriptDic As Variant
Dim arr As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim x As Integer

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("AGGREGATE")

    Set myRange = .Range("H4:K19")

    Set scriptDic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    arr = myRange.Value

    For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)


        If arr(i, 1) <> "" Then

            scriptDic(arr(i, 1)) = scriptDic(arr(i, 1)) + arr(i, 2)

        End If

    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    .Range("M4:P19").ClearContents

    myRange.Range("F1").Resize(scriptDic.Count, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(scriptDic.keys)
    myRange.Range("G1").Resize(scriptDic.Count, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(scriptDic.items)
    myRange.Range("H1").Resize(scriptDic.Count, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(scriptDic.items)
    myRange.Range("I1").Resize(scriptDic.Count, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(scriptDic.items)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End With
```

I am assuming that it has to do with this section but I'm not very good with dimensional arrays.

```
        For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)

        If arr(i, 1) <> "" Then

            scriptDic(arr(i, 1)) = scriptDic(arr(i, 1)) + arr(i, 2)

        End If
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Your issue is that you are writing exactly the same thing (`Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(scriptDic.items)`) to three different columns.  Naturally, the same thing is going to be written to those three columns.

Comment: I'm struggling to work out what you are trying to do.  Your question seems to be implying you are just wanting to write out exactly the same thing as you read in, but your posted code seems to be getting a sum of the values in column I based on the keys in column H (i.e. the equivalent of a `=SUMIF(H:H,F4,I:I)`, once column F is set to the de-duplicated values from column H)

Comment: So the first column is a Key to the "skill level" and the next three columns are broken down by type of pay "st hrs" "ot hrs" and "dt hrs" if there are 2 skill level 3's with "st, ot, and dt" hrs listed for each row. it would consolidate all into 1 row for skill level 3 totaling up each column "st ot and dt"

skill ST OT DT
"3     2     2    2"

"3     2     3    2"

would be:
3   4  5  4
I'm totaling up raw data into aggregate data for each skill level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this purpose, I would get rid of the `Dictionary`, and just use `RemoveDuplicates` to obtain the unique key values.  Then I would use `SUMIF` to get the desired answers:

```
Sub test()
    Dim numRows As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("AGGREGATE")

        'Clear existing contents of column M:P
        .Range("M4", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 3)).ClearContents

        'Copy keys to column M
        numRows = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row - 3
        .Range("M4").Resize(numRows, 1).Value = .Range("H4").Resize(numRows, 1).Value
        'Generate unique list
        .Range("M4").Resize(numRows, 1).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo

        'Calculate answers in column N to P
        numRows = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row - 3
        .Range("N4").Resize(numRows, 3).Formula = "=SUMIF($H:$H,$M4,I:I)"

        'Convert formulas to values
        .Range("N4").Resize(numRows, 3).Value = .Range("N4").Resize(numRows, 3).Value

    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: SUMIF is definitely the easier way to go about it. Thank you! after looking over this code it makes much more sense and is very straight forward with what I was trying to achieve.